# Trying on Kerberos Authentication in Elasticsearch Trial Version

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kerberos

I have setup elasticsearch (version 7.1) and activated the Trial version to try out on the SSO Kerberos features.

1) I have created a krb5.conf file and put the -Djava.security.krb5.conf in the jvm.options configuration file

2) I have created a new user in the Active Directory and put the service principal name -> HTTP/{the full FQDN}@DOMAIN.NAME to generate the keytab file

3) I have updated the elasticsearch.yml file to include the following:
    xpack.security.authc.realms.kerberos.kerb1:
        order:1
        keytab.path:

4) executed the following into Elasticseearch
POST _security/role_mapping
{
    "kerbrolemapping":{
        "enabled": true,
        "roles":["monitoring_user"],
        "rules": {
            "field": { "username": "user1@DOMAIN.INTERNAL" }
        }
    }
}

What should be the expected behavior when I enter the Kibana URL? My result is that it show the Login page after I enter the Kibana URL. Should it be auto-login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.1/kerberos-realm.html):
[image]

At the moment, the only SSO option is with [SAML](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.1/saml-guide.html), though [PKI looks to be coming soon](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/7341)

Comment: I missed that NOTE section, was just busy looking on the configuration. Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: PKI SSO in Kibana was released yesterday: https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-7-4-0-released